# RouteServiceProvider nested category binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have a route like this

> Route::get('/{zoneSlug}/{categorySlug}/{sightSlug}', ...

example:

`{zoneSlug}` has one form like  London or Paris

`{categorySlug}` has many form like:

**cat**

or: **cat/subcat**

or: **car/subcat/subcat3/..**

and `{sightSlug}` has one form like eiffel

So I have like these address:

```
 example.com/paris/category/effel
 ...
 example.com/paris/category/subcategory2/.../subcategory5/effel
```

I try binding it in `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
.
        Route::bind('zoneSlug' , function ($value) {return Zone::whereSlug($value)->firstOrFail();});


        Route::bind('categorySlug', function ($categorySlug, $route) {dd($route);
          $zone = $route->parameter('zoneSlug');
          return Category::whereSlug($categorySlug)->firstOrFail();
        });

        Route::bind('sightSlug', function ($sightSlug, $route) {dd($route);
          $zone = $route->parameter('zoneSlug');
          $category = $route->parameter('categorySlug');
          return Sight::whereZones_id($zone->id)->whereCategories_id($category->id)->whereSlug($sightSlug)->firstOrFail();
        });
```

binding code works for: `example.com/paris/category/effel`    ...but not for

```
example.com/paris/category/subcategory2/.../subcategoryn/effel
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to overthink your URI structure. Your categories are better located in the query string like 
`example.com/paris/eiffel?categories=category/subcategory,category/subcategor2` or `example.com/paris/eiffel?category=category/subcategory&category=category/subcategory2`.